FailoverTansport successfully reconnect but then immediatelly fails with EOFException
The issue is not happening anymore, but we are trying to understand what happened. We are using ActiveMQ Classic 5.16.x, and we had the exception below happening over and over, the logs say that the client was reconnecting successfully to the FailoverTransport, but right away it would fail with an EOFException and then keep trying this non-stop. What are the reasons this could happen? A network issue or a broker issue? Unfortunately we lost the broker logs when the instance was terminated so that side of the story is lost, but want to make changes so that we can handle this better next time.
[2024-11-28 09:06:00] [ActiveMQ Task-2] INFO   [FailoverTransport]  Successfully reconnected to <BROKER>
[2024-11-28 09:06:00] [ActiveMQ Transport: <BROKER>/<IP>:61616@54512] WARN   [FailoverTransport]  Transport (<BROKER>/<IP>:61616@54512) failed, reason:  , attempting to automatically reconnect
java.io.EOFException: null
at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392) ~[?:1.8.0_412]
at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:275)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:221)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:213)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:196)

The previous code runs in an on-prem server that connects to our broker which is in Cloud infra behind a load balancer. My understanding is that FailoverTransport connects to the broker and the logs report a successful reconnect which makes me think the broker is reachable but then I see the EOFException which now makes me believe that although the broker is reachable something is going wrong when trying to read from the socket connection.
